Plotly Animated Scatterplot where only one point shows text in Python
I have a dataframe with football player stats including value X for the x-axis, Y for the y-axis, and then player name and 'year of stats'. I'm using year of stats for the animation frame, but i want to specifically follow one player over the course of the animation to see their stats move across the fig.
d = {'player_names': ['player_A','player_A', 'player_B', 'player_B','player_C','player_C'],
'player_stat_x': ['10', '15', '5', '8', '7', '9'],
'player_stat_y':['1', '3', '2', '1', '4', '4'], 
'player_year': ['2003', '2004','2003', '2004','2003', '2004']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


fig = px.scatter(df.sort_values(['player_year']), 
                 x="player_stat_x", 
                 y="player_stat_y",
                 animation_frame = "player_year",
                 text = ??
)

I'm trying to follow player A from year 2003 -> 2004, but i'm not sure how to approach this. Putting the 'player_names' column into the text field shows all names, which is not what i want. I only want the name for player_A to be showing. I'm new to plotly and lost on how to get this kind of result, or if it's even possible.

What you could do is use conditional logic to create a "text" column, that keeps player_A string, but changes all others to ''. That will leave only the player a text.
Also, you may want your dataframe for your x and y to be numerical, not strings
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'



d = {'player_names': ['player_A','player_A', 'player_B', 'player_B','player_C','player_C'],
'player_stat_x': [10, 15, 5, 8, 7, 9],
'player_stat_y':[1, 3, 2, 1,4, 4], 
'player_year': ['2003', '2004','2003', '2004','2003', '2004']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)



# Add a column to show text only for player_A
df['text'] = df['player_names'].apply(lambda x: x if x == 'player_A' else '')

# Create the scatter plot
fig = px.scatter(df.sort_values(['player_year']), 
                 x="player_stat_x", 
                 y="player_stat_y",
                 animation_frame="player_year",
                 text='text'
)

# Show the plot
pio.show(fig)

